# Missing results in YouTube API search

Tags: youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

I'm making a call to the YouTube API, and as of last week, it's no longer consistently finding the newest posted videos on a specific channel.

I'm using the actual "Try this API" window in the docs (here's a link with the parameters already entered):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22snippet%22%2C%22channelId%22%3A%22UCi8e0iOVk1fEOogdfu4YgfA%22%2C%22maxResults%22%3A10%2C%22order%22%3A%22date%22%7D

and when querying this channel:

https://www.youtube.com/user/movieclipsTRAILERS/videos

I'm no longer getting a full list of the latest uploads. Just looking at the list of uploads, and comparing it to the API response, of the last 12 uploads on the channel, only 5 of them are included in the response.

To compare, here is another Channel search with parameters already included:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22snippet%22%2C%22channelId%22%3A%22UCsn6cjffsvyOZCZxvGoJxGg%22%2C%22maxResults%22%3A10%2C%22order%22%3A%22date%22%7D

and the queried channel's video list:

https://www.youtube.com/user/CorridorDigital/videos

These match up exactly as you'd expect.

Here is the HTTP request generated for the search:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCi8e0iOVk1fEOogdfu4YgfA&maxResults=10&order=date&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
```

I'm completely at the end of my rope here as to why the list of videos is having certain videos filtered out of the search results. It seems unique to the channel, but I can't imagine why the API would behave differently for certain channels.

Comment: I can confirm that YouTube API search is partly broken -- nothing is ever returned for `youtube.search.list` with type=live and channelId set. It used to work like charm about a week ago.

Comment: Thanks. That at least makes me feel better about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue.
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&maxResults=50&channelId=UCuQNLnncEruW0pllaE0ZeKQ&key=...

no longer returns all videos sorted by latest first

Temporary Fix:
adding &publishedAfter=2019-xx-xxT00:00:00Z helped

Still not perfect:
but published after 2 months ago and published after 6 months ago return different results although there are more than 50 videos in the last month (so sorted by latest first should give the same 50 in both cases) !!!

Comment: We're not the only ones. There's actually an issue tracker active about it here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141255579 - but there doesn't seem to be any desire to fix the issue from Google which is leading me to believe it's somewhat intentional.

Comment: this is a temporary fix adding "&publishedAfter=2019-xx-xxT00:00:00Z" so for the last month add "&publishedAfter=2019-08-25T00:00:00Z" to the end of the request string

Comment: Sad, it's 2021, and I still have to use the publishedAfter hack

Answer (score 0):

The other workaround is to use the following series of call:

1) Get the upload playlist using Channels.list:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=contentDetails&id=UCupvZG-5ko_eiXAupbDfxWw&fields=items(contentDetails%252FrelatedPlaylists%252Fuploads%252Cid)&_h=12&

2) Then use playlistitems.list to get the latest videos:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=snippet&playlistId=UUHnyfMqiRRG1u-2MsSQLbXA&_h=6&

solution found at:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141255579